# Issue with function macro

Tags: c, function, c-preprocessor

*The Practice of Programming* book says:

> One of the most serious problems with function macros is that a parameter that
>   appears more than once in the definition might be evaluated more than once; if the
>   argument in the call includes an expression with side effects, the result is a subtle bug.
>   This code attempts to implement one of the character tests from :

```
#define isupper(c) ((c) >= 'A' && (c) <= 'Z')
```

> Note that the parameter c occurs twice in the body of the macro. If i supper is called
>   in a context like this,

```
while (isupper(c = getchar()))
```

> then each time an input character is greater than or equal to A, it will be
>   discarded and another character read to be tested against Z.

I do not understand how a char greater >= A can be discarded.

Comment: Note that the issue can be fixed by `#define isupper(c) ((unsigned)(c)-'A'<='Z'-'A')`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since macro definitions are expanded textually into the program before the actual compilation,

```
isupper(c = getchar())
```

would expand to

```
((c = getchar()) >= 'A' && (c = getchar()) <= 'Z')
```

which by the short-circuiting rule for `&&` calls `getchar` twice iff it returns `>= 'A'` the first time and assign `c` the value returned by the second call.

Comment: "iff" == "if and only if". (Often used in math)